# Configuring nginx to allow only https traffic

Tags: linux, nginx, digital-ocean, vps

I am super new to linux environment, and trying to configure a vps server to only allow  https requests. I have read nginx documentation and tried various rewrite and return statements, changing server blocks etc. But what I have achieved so far, site serves on http and https both with following config.

What I want to achieve is to configure this subdomain admin.example.com to serve only https requests.

I am editing the config at this location: /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name admin.example.com;


    #return 301 https://admin.example.com$request_uri;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.byrides.com/fullchain.pem; # man                                                                                                                                                             aged by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.byrides.com/privkey.pem; # m                                                                                                                                                             anaged by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to setup two server directives, one for port 80 which will redirect the traffic to port 443.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name admin.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.byrides.com/fullchain.pem; # man                                                                                                                                                           aged by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.byrides.com/privkey.pem; # m                                                                                                                                                             anaged by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also add "Strict-Transport-Security" and "Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests" headers

Comment: Normally this should work, in my case I am using Auth0 service, and it goes into a login loop with this configuration. Any ideas? What is happening is Auth0 tries to  call h t tp://admin.example.com as callback url after login, nginx redirects it to https address, it calls auth0 login screen again and again.

Comment: I think you need to change the `redirect_uri` setting or rules of the [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/users/redirecting-users), also remember to clear all the caches. You also need to check your application for non-https links (I usually use https://www.whynopadlock.com to help check my contents to ensures all the images/urls are correctly point to https).

Comment: The config for port 80 will send a response to the browser asking the browser to redirect itself to 443? What if I want to not allow http at all and only allow https?

Comment: @variable you can try by simply removing the server directive for port 80 and move the `server_name` line to the server directive for port 443.